# Why can't I view these images in my cpanel?(not a caching issue)

Tags: http-status-code-404, cpanel

So Im fixing the gallery page on this website https://gilbertmovingandstorage.com/gallery.html as you can see certain images aren't loading? I uploaded them in the img folder on the cpanel. I can see them right next to those images that are visible in the gallery? The img src has no typos and its not a caching issue because I can't see these images in incognito either? Please someone help me I'm sick of all these issues! This project is taking me too long

here's proof that the images are in the folder https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUqz9.jpg

and here's a pic of two images and there src url. One can be viewed on the site and the other one can't? Even though there's no typo  https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjtvl.jpg

Also looking at the source in the devtools then opening the img folder then the gallery_img folder I don't see the images there? I only see the ones that are visible on the site? So does that mean iit is a caching issue, and if it is why then can't I see it in incognito or when I clear the cache??

Answer (score 0):

I just loaded the URL and all the images loaded correctly for me.[image]